# Create a valid RSS Feed on a page on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, rss, rss-reader

I have a website that already has a valid RSS feed on the blog section which is being pulled up. The articles on this blog page are published as Posts. Now in addition to the blogs, we also have e-books and whitepapers in the 'Resources' section of out website (where the blog section also resides).

I want to create a RSS feed on the resources page, which could read any new blogs, e-books and whitepapers added to the Resources page. Since these e-books and whitepapers are not published as post, I'm finding it hard to create an RSS feed that can read them. We plan on adding this RSS feed to our email newsletters which will need to have any new blog, e-books or whitepaper added on the site.

Will appreciate some ideas and best way to do this!

Our website is a custom theme and pages are designed as templates.

Answer (score 0):

This should be as simple as adding a URL parameter depending on your custom post type. Without specifying a URL parameter, wordpress assumes you mean the 'post' type.

For example, https://website.com/rss/?post_type=e-book
or 
https://website.com/feed/?post_type=whitepaper&category=something

To combine post types in your /feed page, try this:

```
function combined_posttypes_rss($qv) {
    if (isset($qv['feed']) && !isset($qv['post_type']))
    $qv['post_type'] = array('post', 'blogs', 'e-books', 'whitepapers');
    return $qv;
}
add_filter('request', 'combined_posttypes_rss');
```

Comment: Here's what I'm thinking - a possible way to use the Resources page to plug the valid RSS in and then use that RSS to obtain new blogs, e-books and whitepapers on email templates. 

My template wouldn't allow multiple feed sources so how do I plug in a valid RSS on my custom resources page?

Comment: Try adding the above (I've edited my answer) to your theme's functions.php file

Comment: Thanks @Luke but I didn't see any change in the default feed.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Tested it my end and it works fine. Make sure the post types identically match the database names of yours.